# emacs on mac: GPG issue with ssh

Tags: ssh, emacs, gnupg

Problem:

- cannot open ssh dir or files
- but ssh connexion works for magit: it requires a passphrase for the key .ssh/id_rsa, and then proceedes.
- so the issue seems to be that simply trying to connect to the server fails because tramp does not ask for the rsa key?

Message:
Error while decrypting with "/usr/local/bin/gpg":
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: decrypt_message failed: Unknown system error

Detailed description:
When trying to open a remote directory (through dired) or a remote file with emacs (using the command: </ssh:name@remote:file>, i get the above erro (even before the password is required). Then the password is asked. I enter it, and the system freezes.
Yet, everything works smoothly when using magit to synchronise with github through ssh.

Config:
mac: BigSur 11.6
emacs: 27.2 (9.0) (emacs for OsX)

Any help would be great!
Best
thibault

Comment: There is no GPG involved in a regular Tramp session. You really need to add more details to explain exactly what you are trying to do and how it involves `gpg`. Also, on Mac, we always need to ask, which Emacs (Aquamacs, Emacs for OsX, Homebrew, something else?)

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a comment. Expressing gratitude but failing to [edit] your question to address the concerns I raised seems like an odd reaction.

Comment: Thank your very much for your comment.

I'm just trying to connect to a remote server. 

I'm using emacs for OsX.

I also don't really understand how gpg enters in the story. It really comes out of the blue, and i don't even know what process is involved (no idea how to find out more information).

Comment: Does `gpg` work from the command line? Maybe you have installed it but not configured it?

Comment: It seems that is has to do with id_rsa keys. 

When i connect through magit, it asks for the key, and then works smoothly. But tramp does not requires the key, so i guess it is missing, and prevent the connexion. I edited the question alongs these remarks. But still cannot solve the problem ...
Besides, yes, gpg works.